# Java Android Studio Null Pointer Exception on Jaunt Webcrawler

Tags: java, android, browser, web-scraping, jaunt-api

I am trying to run the simple Jaunt example from the website and got an error for Null Pointer Exception. I am not sure what to do because there is very little support for using Jaunt in Android Studio. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{
        UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
        userAgent.visit("http://jaunt-api.com/examples/signup.htm");         
    }
    catch(JauntException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Here is the error I got when I ran it:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Transport.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
```

The error was on the userAgent.visit line.

This is where I got the code: http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm

Comment: hi, can you provide where you are following the tutorial or where you got this code?

Comment: @GastónSaillén http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm

Comment: @GastónSaillén Please help me... I'm still pretty new to Java and am only 16 years old and trying to work on a project for school.

Comment: sorry dude, i was out of the pc for a little bit to catch dinner, can you post more of your code? where you are doing this try

Comment: @GastónSaillén thanks for your help. I am doing this in the onCreate in Android studio.

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace please

Comment: @LUKER as mentioned we need to see the whole crash logs not only the message line

Comment: @LUKER check the logs internet permission too, if possible paste here for us.

Comment: any resolutions that worked?

Comment: I am running into this error as well after adding both `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATUS` permissions to the manifest. Looks like I'll try Jsoup instead :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs on Android if you failed to connect your HttpURLConnection first - or can be a side effect if you forgot to add the internet permission to your manifest

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your url is correct

```
http://jaunt-api.com/examples/signup.htm
```

this is definitely wrong url

then

Here is a workaround class for NPE that you can use in OkHttp

```
public class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {


    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, annotations);
        return (Converter<ResponseBody, Object>) body -> {
            if (body.contentLength() == 0) return null;
            return delegate.convert(body);
        };
    }
}
```

In your OkHttp client builder addNetworkInterceptor first, order matters

Answer (score -1):

Try add the permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```